# Getting Ecto.Query.CastError when querying in phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

So I copied a **query** where it will preload a user associated in it.

The problem is that its throwing an **ecto.query.cast** error and I can't seem to find the solution.

**query**

```
def get_avatar!(id) do
IO.inspect(id)

query =
  from(
    p in AssocApp.Accounts.Avatar,
    where: p.user_id == ^id,
    select: p,
    preload: [:user]
  )

Repo.get!(Avatar, query)
end
```

**user schema**

```
schema "users" do
field(:password, :string)
field(:username, :string)
has_one(:avatar, AssocApp.Accounts.Avatar)

timestamps()end
```

**avatar schema**

```
schema "avatars" do
field(:firstname, :string)
field(:lastname, :string)
field(:pic_url, :string)
belongs_to(:user, AssocApp.Accounts.User)

timestamps()end
```

`@doc false
  def changeset(avatar, attrs) do
    avatar
    |> cast(attrs, [:firstname, :lastname, :pic_url, :user_id])
    # |> validate_required([:firstname, :lastname, :pic_url])end`

**avatar controller**

```
def show(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
avatar = Accounts.get_avatar!(id)
render(conn, "show.json", avatar: avatar)end
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Note we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Repo.get!/2` fetches a record by its primary key but you're passing a query to it. You need to use `Repo.one!/1`:

```
Repo.one!(query)
```